# Transmission: permission denied on USB disk

Tags: raspbmc, hard-drive, storage

I have Raspberry Pi running RaspBMC with a WD MyBook connected using USB. The drive is automatically mounted to `/media/My Book`. I have created a folder `/media/My Book/downloads` and I have set Trasmission's download directory to be `/media/My Book/downloads`.

When I try to download a file, Transmission says

```
Error: Permission denied (/media/My Book/downloads/The.Simpsons.S24E09.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION [PublicHD]/The.Simpsons.S24E09.720p.HD
```

ls -la gives me

```
drwx------ 1 pi       0 Dec 15 16:24 downloads
```

So I guess the problem is that transmission runs under different user than `pi` and cannot write to the folder. However when I execute

```
chmod 777 downloads -R
```

the operations succeeds without any error but the permissions do not change, they stay 700 just for the owner.

What am I doing wrong and how can I enabled Transmission to write to that directory?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem was the way the USB disk was automonted. I mounted it manualy with mount -t ntfs-3g and it started working.

Comment: Same happened to me. With the HDD auto-mounted all the permissions were set to 0700, but mounting it with `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=pi,gid=pi /dev/sda1 /media/HDD/` they are 0777 and transmission works perfectly, really weird.

Comment: My ExFAT was auto-mounting with `exfat defaults,auto,umask=000,users,rw 0 0`, I changed that to mount with `pi` user IDs `exfat defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0` and it worked. Check this AskUbuntu answer: [Ownership/permission problem with automounting exfat drive](https://askubuntu.com/a/923701/184896)

Answer (score 25):

After lots of reading and frustration. First of all, make sure the normal user has read and write acces to the USB drive. The correct 'non-root' fix for having write acces to the USB drive is:

**Step 1: Stop transmission daemon**

```
sudo service transmission-daemon stop
```

**Step 2: Add `pi` to debian-transmission group**

```
sudo usermod -a -G debian-transmission pi
```

**Step 3: changing the daemon-user**

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon
```

Change `USER` to `pi`.

**Step 4 Change the rights of the configuration files folder**

```
sudo chown -R pi /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/
sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/settings.json
```

**Step 5: Set the correct permissions for the download / incomplete folders**

```
sudo chown -R pi /somewhere/downloads
sudo chown -R pi /somewhere/incomplete
```

**Step 5: Start transmission daemon**

```
sudo service transmission-daemon start
```

*Compiled from:*

- https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=8714
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Transmission

Comment: This is the only correct answer. Running as `root` is wrong. Doing a `chmod 777` is wrong. Setting the correct group and user is the only correct way.

Comment: Maybe it’s correct answer but it doesn’t work for me.

Comment: I have renamed my username from `pi` to something else. However, when I do `ls -al` it appears my files are still in a `pi` group. With the above instructions, should I change every instance of `pi` to my new username, or do any refer to the group which is still `pi`? These instructions don't work when I changed every `pi` to my username.

Comment: @Keavon 

"should I change every instance of pi to my new username"

Yes, also is the new user in the debian-tranmission group?

Comment: I was having the input/output problem with transmission, but this make it works, thanks a lot!! This is the right way of doing it

Answer (score 10):

I'm no linux expert, but you could try this, might work.
Most of this is info came from
http://www.superfecta.ca/?p=44

```
sudo service transmission-daemon stop
sudo nano /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon
```

change

```
USER=debian-transmission
```

to

```
USER=root
ctrl-x
Y
# hit enter to overwrite
sudo service transmission-daemon start
```

I know running as root is a big linux no no (not sure if that counts as running in root) but it worked for me so I'm fine with it. You could try `USER=pi` instead but I got no love there, so I stuck with root

Comment: Of course running as root works, it's just a security risk.

Comment: Just something to add: Linux uses /etc/fstab file to set up mount points and permissions/ownership of the drive. So, you have three choices, run transmission as root, run transmission as the owner of the folder where the drive resides (`ls -l` will tell you who owns it), or modify the /etc/fstab file to show a different owner (i.e. debian-transmission).

Comment: I was facing a similar problem with saving torrents on a NAS drive mounted as guest. I tried all solutions mentioned everywhere, but nothing worked for me, so I gave up and made transmission-daemon run as root. I don't like it, but it's the only thing that works.

Comment: This is wrong and daemons like this should never run with root privileges. You should remove this answer because this will damage other peoples setup.

Answer (score 7):

None of the answers here worked for me, so I am writing a new one referencing https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-torrentbox/ which worked great for me and allowed me to run transmission as `pi` user to access my USB drive. This is not directly answering the OP but this question is very popular (first Google result) for this sort of problem so I put it here.

Enter:

```
sudo vi /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon
```

and find `USER` in the top of the file and change to:

```
USER=pi
```

Then we need to `chown` some files into our permissions scope:

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi /etc/transmission-daemon
sudo chown -R pi:pi /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon
sudo chown -R pi:pi /var/lib/transmission-daemon
```

And then run (this is really important else the daemon from the service will just run as `debian-transmission`)

```
sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/transmission-daemon.service
```

and find `user` there and change to:

```
user=pi
```

and the reload the service unit

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

And finally we need to symlink our settings file to the pi home directory and give it permissions:

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/pi/.config/transmission-daemon/
sudo ln -s /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json /home/pi/.config/transmission-daemon/
sudo chown -R pi:pi /home/pi/.config/transmission-daemon/
```

And then start transmission again:

```
sudo service transmission-daemon start
```

and you're done. It should now work.

Comment: This was great! In addition to this I also had to make sure, that the mounted external harddrive had the main folder (in my case /mnt/raid1) as listable by other users.

Comment: So even though pi:debian-transmission had 774 on /mnt/raid1/_download/torrent-complete it wasn't enough. I also had to do chmod o+X /mnt/raid1

Answer (score 5):

I believe your problem is your USB stick is formatted as NFTS or FAT, filesystems that do not support the per-user/group permissions. The solution is to reformat as ext4. If you do that, you will also have much less lag if you are using your Pi as a media center. The drivers for the Pi are much faster when you use ext4.

Comment: Considerably faster than ntfs-3g? Could you show some data to back up that statement?

Comment: @Joseph It was mostly a problem with the raspberry pi 1 as NTFS is quite CPU-heavy. Here's a benchmark of transfer speeds: http://www.htpcguides.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/raspberry-pi-2-vs-banana-pi-benchmarks-sata-usb-ftp-upload.png

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the main things people are overlooking is that you *should* mount your usb/external drive in **/mnt**/myUsbDrive folder, and ***NOT*** in **/media/pi**/myUsbDrive.

```
sudo umount /media/pi/usb_disk
sudo mkdir /mnt/usb_disk
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=pi,gid=pi /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb_disk
```

I tried every single answer given on this discussion (including root) in a hundred different ways with different options and could not get transmission to save on my usb SSD drive. Then while reading something different, it was mentioned not to mount in /media/pi since daemons or other groups may not have access.  So i mount the USB drive to /mnt/usb_disk, set the paths in /etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json to /mnt/usb_disk/downloads and transmission starts saving to the disk.

FYI, I do have user=pi in /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon.

FYI, I did change owner of /mnt/usb_disk/downloads to pi and group to debian-transmission with 777 permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the file system was the problem for me. Luckily it was a brand new usb hard drive so wasn't an issue to format it.

I first formatted the hard drive to ext4

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/<usb disk> -L <diskname>
```

Then I mounted the usb hard drive

```
sudo mount /dev/<usb disk> /mnt/<my mount folder>
```

Once mounted I changed the group for the hard drive to `debian-`

```
sudo chgrp debian-transmission /mnt/rpi_nas/
```

Finally I added the pi user to debian-transmission group and it worked great for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo chown debian-transmission /downloads
```

where /downloads is the directory you want your downloads to be in (or mount location).

this is safer than using root.

this gives the 'user' known as 'debian-transmission' rights to the folder

Answer (score 1):

I found the same solution as Igor and puigcerber. My drive was set to auto mount, so I edited my fstab to remove the automount, then used `sudo mount -t vfat -o uid=pi,gid=pi /dev/sda1 /media/*mymountpoint/`

Answer (score 1):

While biketire's answer is correct debian switched to systemd recently and you have to change the user now here

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/transmission-daemon.service`

and make sure that in the section

```
[Service]
```

you have the line

```
User=pi
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

After a lot of reading and frustration.

First of all, make sure the normal user has read and write access to the USB drive. The correct 'non-root' fix for having write access to the USB drive is:

**Step 1: Stop transmission daemon**

`sudo service transmission-daemon stop`

**Step 2: Add pi to debian-transmission group**

`sudo usermod -a -G debian-transmission pi`

**Step 3: changing the daemon-user**

`sudo nano /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon`

Change USER to pi.

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/transmission-daemon.service`

Change USER to pi.

**Step 4: Change the rights of the configuration files folder**

`sudo chown -R pi /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/
sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info/settings.json`

**Step 5: Set the correct permissions for the download / incomplete folders**

`sudo chown -R pi /somewhere/downloads
sudo chown -R pi /somewhere/incomplete`

**Step 6: Start transmission daemon**

`sudo service transmission-daemon start`

Answer (score 0):

Once you change the transmission-daemon user to root the permissions problem is gone with either a usb or smb share.

sudo nano /etc/init.d/transmission-daemon

then change the user line to:

USER=root

Comment: That's a security risk.

Comment: This is wrong and daemons like this should never run with root privileges. You should remove this answer because this will damage other peoples setup.

Answer (score 0):

The problem relates to FAT not recognising multiple users.

If you use a line in your fstab file such as
/dev/[your dev] /mnt/usb1 vfat defaults,uid=65534,gid=65534,dmask=000,fmask=111 0 0

it should mount your filesystem with folders 777 and files as 666 owned by "nobody" belonging to "nogroup"

you will need to remount (or reboot) for the changes to be seen.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a working solution.

I turned of autosharing removable devices in XBIAN settings and added the disk to shares.conf by hand

```
[mybook]
    path = /media/mybook
    guest ok = yes
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    writeable = yes
    force user = xbian
```

Just adding it to shares.conf is not enough, autosharing must be turned off.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar permissions problem.

I tried following sabi's solution blindly and found that it did not work.
Not only that, but I believe it's a bit overkill.

In my situation I simply overlooked the fact that **transmission-daemon** was running as user:**debian-transmission**.

Hence in order to grant permission for transmission-daemon to write to a folder(**folder_name**), you just need to do the following commands:

```
chgrp -R folder_name
chmod -R 765 folder_name
```

This is assuming of course that you've properly configured **settings.json** already

Answer (score -1):

chmod 777 should give every user all permissions to a file or directory.
If that doesn't work, it's likely that the user that execute that chmod command does not own the directory or file.
For example, if root owns /media/My Book/ and the pi user will not be able to change the permissions of that file.
The three numbers you pass to the chmod command affect the owner, the group, and everybody else, in that order. Thus the most common settings for a directory are "chmod 755 somedirectory". That mean the owner can read, write and change into the directory, but group and everyone else can only read files and change into the directory.

Comment: This answer really doesn't answer the question. The asker has already tried chmodding the file and it didn't work.