# Transmission: access denied

Tags: hard-drive, permissions

I installed transmission on my raspberry pi and set it up to download directly onto a mounted external hdd. The drive is mounted using following fstab entry:

/dev/sda1       /mnt/old        ntfs    uid=pi,gid=pi,umask=000   0       0

I've added the user debian-transmission to group pi and also added user pi to group debian-transmission, just to be safe. The service runs under user pi.

I've tried every suggestion I found here [Transmission: permission denied on USB disk](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4378/transmission-permission-denied-on-usb-disk) but none of them worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before we continue, [a default Debian/Raspbian installation has read-only support for NTFS](https://wiki.debian.org/NTFS). Try installing ntfs-3g for read & write access:

```
sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g
```

If this doesn't work right away, make sure to power cycle your Raspberry Pi (`sudo shutdown`, disconnect all cables, wait 10 seconds, connect all cables and let it boot again).

Then try to make user pi owner of the root folder of the USB device.

```
sudo chown -R pi:pi /dev/sda1
```

I don't know how familiar you are with GNU/Linux, but here is the explanation of the suggested commands:

- sudo => super user do
- apt-get install => install using apt (the "advanced packaging tool")
- chown -R => change ownership, -R makes it recursive (includes all subfolders & files)

Comment: I tried: brw-rw---- 1 pi pi 8, 1 Mar 12 19:48 /dev/sda1
Sadly, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try to make a subfolder as root (eg. /dev/sda1/transmission), change the ownership for that subfolder to user pi, point Transmission to that subfolder, and then reboot (or restart the Transmission process)?

Comment: That didn't work, but I noticed something weird. The folder /mnt/old (whch is the mounting point of sda1) has pi:pi 777 permissions, but I can't write anything as user pi, I have to be root. That doesn't seem to be normal. It may be an issue with the way the drive is mounted.

Comment: Are you using the default Raspbian NTFS driver? That one is read-only.

Comment: Ah, problem found. I was missing the proper drivers for ntfs. Installing the package ntfs-3g did the trick.

Comment: Thanks, Max. I don't remember installing that the first couple of times when I set up my raspberry, so I didn't think the drivers were an issue.