# Transmission unable to write on usb disk

Tags: usb, file-sharing

I have a raspberry pi 3 B+ running raspbian.

I installed transmission torrent client, and I connected an usb disk to save files there.

For some reason, I'm not able to write in to the disk.

Until now, I tried:

1. Change user group of transmission daemon as explain on this guide. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/29538
2. Partition and format the disk as ext4, adding `chmod 777 -R .`. I tested runining: `sudo -u debian-transmission touch file.txt` works perfectly.
3. I added fstab entry like `UUID=c8299c71-1baf-4760-bd91-07a6cd428a7c /media/pi/c8299c71-1baf-4760-bd91-07a6cd428a7c ext4 defaults 0`
4. I turn on the logs of transmission to see whats going on: https://pastebin.com/FqFGpaEa

Comment: are you able to copy files to the USB disk using the file manager or using a shell command

Comment: @jsotola To quote the OP, `sudo -u debian-transmission touch file.txt` works perfectly.

Comment: @jstola Yes, I ran `sudo -u debian-transmission mv cold_galaxy-HD.jpg cold_galaxy-HD2.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my right problems with this :

```
sudo mount.cifs //XXX/XXX/XXXXXXX /home/pi/usbRemoteDrive/routerDrive -o uid=debian-transmission,gid=debian-transmission,ip=192.168.X.XXX,user=,pass=,vers=1.0
```

The answer was : uid=debian-transmission,gid=debian-transmission

I also added pi user in debian-transmission group :

```
sudo usermod -a -G debian-transmission pi
```

I added a cron on boot who mount the disk cause i was not abble to do this with fstab...

```
@boot /home/pi/Scripts/boot.sh
```

boot.sh :

```
#! /bin/sh
sudo mount.cifs //XXX/XXX/XXXXXXX /home/pi/usbRemoteDrive/routerDrive -o uid=debian-transmission,gid=debian-transmission,ip=192.168.X.XXX,user=,pass=,vers=1.0
exit 0
```

I don't know if it's a good solution but it is working

Comment: While interesting, the OP uses a local ext4 file system, not CIFS.